# How does OS combine discrete and integrated graphics cards?

Tags: operating-system, directx, gpu

I have a system that has both a discrete and integrated graphics cards (one Nvidia, and the other Intel).
To my surprise I found that I could hook up a monitor to each one individually. 
Moreover, I could play a game in a window on the monitor attached to the discrete card, and drag it to the other monitor attached to the integrated card (albeit with a drop in performance). 
I also noticed that in the first case, only the discrete card was busy, but once I moved the window, both cards were busy.

I realize this is probably not an optimal configuration, but it got me curious as to how the OS handles this situation? There must be some communication going on between the cards for this to work, such as one card doing the actual computation and the other outputting the result. 
Does anyone have a any insight into this?

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you have an intel card and a separate card, much like you have, the integrated is used as default.  When the machine is rendering graphics at a certain threshold, the separate card will kick in and take over.